# Web application show another user's menu list

Tags: asp.net

We have 2 web applications in single IIS Server. 
Suddenly some users getting another user's menu list (tree view).
Even the login user's name also getting changed. 
We haven't made any recent changes to source / database.

Any clues ?

Comment: You say you haven't changed anything, but _something_ has clearly changed. Computers don't do this stuff randomly. There's not enough info here for anyone to realistically suggest what that might be. Double-check all your config, settings etc. related to authentication in the app and the deployed environment and rule each one out. Create a duplicate environment for comparison if you have to, and see what's different. Check that no-one has made an unauthorised change, or deployed the wrong version of the app. If you have any docs saying what the config _should_ be, then compare that to reality.

Comment: the other remote possibility is that your users are logging in as other people (probably in breach of your IT policy). I have seen this happen before, and then they wonder why it causes problems.